# java shortcut like vb with

Tags: java

in VB6 i remember being able to do this (im tired, forgive errors)

```
ssoUser13 = new SSOUser();

with ssoUser13 (
    .setLoginID("ssousr12");
    .setFirstName("User12");
    .setLastName("TestUser12");
    .setEmail("email");
    .setAbbreviation("abbreviation");
    .setPhone("5712948214");
    .setMiddleInitial("N");
    .setAuthenticator(AuthenticatorSystems.AS400);
    .securityPolicy = new Policy();
)
```

does java have a shortcut like that?

Answer (score 3):

Java has a pattern called a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) that's similar.  This isn't part of the language, and is only available on a few classes in the JDK - notably, [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).  In these classes, setters and other modifying methods don't return void - instead they return "this" so that these methods can be chained together, similar to your example.

Answer (score 0):

No, but some libraries provide [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) as an alternative.

Comment: Right, e.g. the builder pattern in Java is often implemented so provide a interface like it.